# Appending uploaded pictures with AJAX in chatbox

Tags: php, jquery

I am building a web chat application. After uploading picture to the server I want to append it to the chat box just as I would do with text messages but it is not working. Here is my PHP code trying to call a JavaScript function to fetch the picture but it is still not working. Any contributions or reference would be appreciated.

PHP code:

```
<?php
//$msgid picture id in database
$msgid = mysqli_insert_id($conn3);
$ipix = "<img src='$thumb'>";
echo "<script>
isendthumb($msgid);
</script>";

?>
```

JavaScript function:

```
<script>
function isendthumb(msgid) {
var requestData = {term: msgid};
$.get('http://localhost/facework/chat/newthumb.php', requestData, function(data) {
$(data).appendTo('div#chats');
}).fail(function(jqXHR) {
//$('div#chats').html('<a> Refresh Page </a>');
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: thanks Jay Blanchard

Comment: however lets say i want to append an uploaded image to a chatbox am calling a function from my php script but the function don't seem to be working